# converting audio file to bytearray: no such file or directory

Tags: android, arrays, file, uri

Im trying to convert an audio file to byte array. where the audio file is fetch through attach file so its in an Uri

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {

        //FileInputStream = reading the file
          fis = new FileInputStream(new File(audioFxUri.getPath()));
          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int n;
          while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                 baos.write(buf, 0, n);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     byte[] bbytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

i followed that code from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597613/onactivityresult-uri-to-byte-array) but once i ran. It gave me an error

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/audio/media/646818: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I also tried to play it with a MediaPlayer and place Uri as its Source

```
  MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
  player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  player.setDataSource(AttachAudio.this,audioFxUri.toString());
  player.prepare();
  player.start();
```

to make sure if the audio file is working or not. Ps. it worked.

Is there something wrong im doing as to why it didnt convert to byte array?

Comment: check extrenal read permission

Comment: @VineshChauhan yes i have the permission for it at the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

The File Uri you have `/external/audio/media/646818` is not an actual File Path, hence it is giving `FileNotFoundException`.

You need to get absolute path from the URI and then read the file accordingly.

You can either use below code:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) 
{
     String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
     Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
     int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

or Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri/41520090) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913427/how-to-get-the-uri-from-mediastore-via-file-path) SO link for other options/methods

Comment: Hi! currently using external storage and nothing related to the database. But i also tried the link u gave. String path = audioFxUri.uri.toString() doesnt seem to recognize ".uri"

Comment: Try using `String path = audioFxUri.toString()`

Comment: in my code i replace fis = new FileInputStream(new File(audioFxUri.getPath())); to audioFxUri.getString() but it still gave the same error

Comment: Could you try other options too? Also, I found another link, more specific to audio, which I feel is more related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913427/how-to-get-the-uri-from-mediastore-via-file-path **Note**: It is not related to SQLite database but is part of ContentResolver

Comment: thanks ill try out other options. i getting a grasp of what youve sent and am looking into other related stuff to it